# Facebook Like button suddenly stopped working some days ago

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I have a Facebook app (Friends & Profile Statistics) with a like button at the following URL:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=120125298051178 (which redirects to
http://apps.facebook.com/statistics)

The like button, linked to the first URL, has stopped working several days ago, showing 0 likes and giving an error when clicked.

I have run the page through Facebook's debugger/linter (developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/), which gives several warnings but no errors (I tried getting rid of the warnings but to no avail as my app runs in an iFrame on Facebook's site).

Using Facebook's Like button tool (developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) I get the same error message for my URL. This tells me it's not a problem with my implementation of the like button but rather with my URL.

Any idea what could be wrong and how this could be fixed?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem with my application (http://ligowe.info - bottom left). The "like" button suddenly stopped working after a couple of years of smooth running.